# Structural equation modeling / path analysis using lavaan

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I'm trying to use the `sem` function, after having defined a simple model as:

```
Model1 <- 'Y ~ X + M
           M ~ X'
sem (Model1, data = A)
```

Where A is a matrix defined with the command

```
A = matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 50)
A[,1] = read.csv2("Mydata1",header = TRUE)
A[,2] = read.csv2("Mydata2", header = TRUE)
A[,3] = read.csv2("Mydata3",header = TRUE)
```

But the software displays:

> Error in lav_data_full(data = data, group = group, cluster = cluster, 
>   :    lavaan ERROR: missing observed variables in dataset: Y M

I've tried also to substitute missing values with means for each variable, but it displays the same error.

Comment: Can you run `summary(A)` or `colnames(A)` and post the output? It looks like the variable names aren’t being read properly.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was in the variable's names! The column's name must be equal to the names given in the definition of the model. Mine were different because of upper-case letters!